# show Next button in keypad of jquery mobile application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am using [jquerymobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com) for my mobile application development. For all the text(type="text") elements its shows Alphabet keypad in Mobile and For (type="number"), it shows number keypad by default and also it shows Go button on bottom right corner of keypad. How can i show the Next button instead of Go for all the input elements except the last element of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I know for iOS the [Previous][Next] buttons are at the top of the keyboard layout. If there is no input to navigate to it's grayed out

- http://jsfiddle.net/xTtmQ/
- http://jsfiddle.net/xTtmQ/embedded/result/ (view on iOS device)
- http://jsfiddle.net/xTtmQ/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/xTtmQ/1/embedded/result/ (TabIndex: view on iOS device)

You might be able to play with the TabIndex as well.

At this time I'm unaware of any custom keyboard options/layouts for HTML5 webapps

[image]